# WPF- some mouse events do not fire

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, itemscontrol, mousedown

I use `ItemsControl` to represent control points of bezier curve in `Canvas`. I need to be able to catch `MouseDown` event on `Ellipse` to retrieve cursor position during movement so I can update bezier curve real-time.

`MouseDown` nor `PreviewMouseDown` works. I've googled a lot and tied plenty of experimenting but I guess that I'm asking wrong questions.

```
<ItemsControl Name="DirectivePointsControl"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding VisibleDirectivePoints}"
                  Width="{Binding ElementName=MainMapImage, Path=ActualWidth}"
                  Height="{Binding ElementName=MainMapImage, Path=ActualHeight}"
                  Focusable="False"
                  >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <jas:DragCanvas x:Name="DirectivePointsCanvas"
                                Background="Transparent"
                                ClipToBounds="True"
                                AllowDragging="True"
                                AllowDragOutOfView="True"
                                Focusable="false"
                                Width="{Binding ElementName=MainMapImage, Path=ActualWidth}"
                                Height="{Binding ElementName=MainMapImage, Path=ActualHeight}"
                                MouseMove="DirectivePointsCanvas_MouseMove"
                                />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DirectivePoint}">
                <Ellipse Height="10" 
                         Width="10" 
                         StrokeThickness="2"
                         Fill="Yellow"
                         Stroke="Black"
                         Focusable="True"
                         Tag="{Binding Path=ID}"
                         MouseDown="Ellipse_MouseDown"
                         PreviewMouseDown="Ellipse_PreviewMouseDown"
                         />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Location.Y}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=Location.X}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.ZIndex" Value="99" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
```

What am I missing ? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Post your event handlers for the `MouseDown` and `PreviewMouseDown` events so we'll know how to help you.

Comment: in those event handlers there is just debug code to determine if the events were caught. They are never executed .. that's my problem.

If I set MouseDown event handler for Canvas it works fine. Just Ellipse is not Working.

Comment: Ok I got it. I use this [dragcanvas](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15354/Dragging-Elements-in-a-Canvas) and they swallowed up the MouseDown event so it did not bubble up